# Magento Orders->Google Sitemap ... since recently a blank page?

Tags: magento

Magento Orders->Google Sitemap ... since recently a blank page?!!!!

Hi since some weeks our sitemap page via Magento Orders->Google Sitemap is empty. Nada! Just a simple white page

This is very frustrating as we dont know how to resolve (and do need to recreate)

And when I click create new, this is the error (create new is the only button we see)

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 151
```

Where do we start to investigate?

Do I need to clean some table?

And I dont understand why this suddenly is a new error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in? Some Admin pages don't display until you do that because of how the ACL system works.

Comment: Many times, cleared caches and all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a faulty bracket not closing in config.xml